# Leap year boolean/get days in this month int (28 - 31)

Tags: java, boolean

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
{ if ((year % 4) != 0)
     return false; 
      else if ((year % 400) == 0)
    return true;  
      else if ((year % 100) == 0)
    return false; 
      else
     return true;
}

public int getDaysInThisMonth()
{ if (month == APRIL || month == JUNE || month == SEPTEMBER || month == NOVEMBER)
        return 30;
  else if (month == FEBRUARY || isLeapYear == false)
        return 28;
       if (isLeapYear == true)
        return 29;
  else return 31;
}
```

SEPTEMBER-DECEMBER are all defined as constants 1-12, working as intended. My problem here is that I'm getting error codes when trying to compile.

```
 symbol:   variable isLeapYear
  location: class Date
Date.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
                   if (isLeapYear == true)
                       ^
  symbol:   variable isLeapYear
  location: class Date

2 errors
```

So why can't it find isLeapYear when it's directly above it? All of the code above the stuff I've posted works as intended.

Comment: from where `month` come from?

Comment: `isLeapYear` is a **method** and not a variable.

Comment: Not what you asked - but your logic is slightly off.  What you've written in `getDaysInThisMonth()` will return 29 for any of the 31-day months in a leap year (once you fix the error as described in the correct answers below).

Comment: What would be the best way to end that part, then? "else return 31;" doesn't mean that for everything else that isn't included above, return 31?

Comment: Or you could call the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library rather than roll-your-own. `boolean isLeapYear = new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 ).year().isLeap();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isLeapYear` is a method, not a variable, so you have to *invoke* it:

```
 if (isLeapYear(year)) {
```

Since it needs that `year` parameter, you have to figure out where that is coming from, too.

Answer (score 0):

Because this

```
if (isLeapYear == true)
```

Is missing the argument (and you don't need to test if a `boolean` equals `true`),

```
if (isLeapYear(year)) // <-- is a leap year
```

or

```
if (! isLeapYear(year)) // <-- not a leap year
```

Where `year` is a variable or integer literal to pass on method invocation.